# wireless connection does not work during boot-up, but connects after login

Tags: 11.10, wireless, network-manager

I have just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10, and the wireless connection now fails to come up at boot-up. When I upgraded to 11.04 I had a problem which was resolved by editing NetworkManager.conf to add

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Now when I start my machine it takes forever to boot up, as it waits for network configuration, and then says it will wait for another 60 seconds. Finally, it gives up and boots without network connection. But once I login the network connection comes up fine. How can I make it do whatever it does after login during the boot sequence instead?

Answer (score 1):

Have now fixed the problem: changed the wireless setting to allow all users to access it.